# In Hero 3D, where can I find "it" in the "red plains"?

Tags: half-minute-hero-the-second-coming

In Hero 3D, an NPC teases me saying that you can find *it* in the *red plains.* In addition there are three shops that are empty and taunt me by saying that I probably can't see it, and they do sell nothing.

What are they talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to mode select and pick Ragnarock. Warp to Porto Village and head north to the place where you tackled QUIZ. Go all the way north and talk to the scientist. This will start an optional quest, **Q37. Crimson World**. Complete it to win the 3D glasses. (Given that the Crimson World is an homage to the Virtual Boy, I suppose that this is what they mean by *it.* If there's one place in the game where the plains are red, this is it.)

By the way, you can go back and talk to the scientist again after completing Q37 for two virtual castle parts.

Now go back to destiny: equip the 3D glasses and do Hero 3 again. Now you can see what the three shops are selling: a red stone that boots offense in the starting village, a blue stone that boosts defense in the south village and a yellow stone that boosts both in the northern village. Buy all three to unlock the Stone Freak title.